# Dreaded "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" Error when executing

Tags: apex, date, method, errormessages

Here is the full Error message:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:Line: 1, Column: 1 Method
>   does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   CompareNewAndOldFiscalPeriod.compareMonths(Integer, Integer)

When trying to execute the code below:

More generally does anyone have a guide on how to trouble shoot this error.  It crops up a lot and seems to have completely different causes in every case.

Execute Anonymous:

```
CompareNewAndOldFiscalPeriod.compareMonths(11/1/2015,1/1/2016);
```

**Class**

```
public class CompareNewAndOldFiscalPeriod {

//Set  up to see if the change in and end date results is moving the opportunity to a different fiscal month.  This is used as a measure of pipeline quality
//Designed to be called by a flow that is evaluating other changes in oppty data.

//find fiscal month of old close date
public static Boolean compareMonths(date OldClose, date NewClose){
    List<Period> OldPeriod= [SELECT Number,Id From Period WHERE type = 'Month' AND StartDate < =:OldClose AND EndDate>=:OldClose LIMIT 1];
    period Per=New period();
    Integer OldMonth=0;
    Per=OldPeriod.get(0);
    OldMonth=per.Number;  


    //find fiscal month of new close date  
    List<period> NewPeriod=[SELECT Number,Id From Period WHERE type = 'Month' AND StartDate < =:NewClose AND EndDate>=:NewClose LIMIT 1];
    period Per2=New period();
    Integer NewMonth=0;
    Per2=NewPeriod.get(0);
    NewMonth=per2.Number;   

    system.debug('New fiscal month is' + NewMonth);

    //compare and return a verdict about whether or not this will count as a change in Fiscal Period
    Boolean verdict=false;
    If(NewMonth>OldMonth){
        verdict=true;

        System.debug('Verdict is '+ verdict);
    }
  return verdict;
}

}
```

Comment: from where you are calling this method ? As per the error message you are passing integer but this method accept date as data type.

Comment: Execute Anonymous:  CompareNewAndOldFiscalPeriod.compareMonths(11/1/2015,1/1/2016);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will call your method in following format.

```
Date startDate = date.parse('11/1/2015');
Date endDate = date.parse('1/1/2016');
compareNewAndOldFiscalPeriod.compareMonths(startDate,endDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your signature takes `(Date, Date)` but you are passing `(Integer, Integer)`.

```
Integer a = 1/1/2015;
Integer b = 1/1/2016;
myMethod(a, b); // incorrect

Date x = Date.newInstance(2015, 1, 1);
Date y = Date.newInstance(2016, 1, 1);
myMethod(x, y); // correct
```